# Skip a map in a specific circumstance

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

I currently have the following map setup to allow me to quickly create a pair of parens by tapping `(` twice, leaving the cursor between them for more typing:

```
imap (( ()<left>
```

Separately, I have another map for skipping over the closing paren when it already exists.  That is, if you type `)` when there is already a `)` to the right of the cursor, instead of inserting another `)` the cursor just jumps over the existing one:

```
inoremap <expr> )  strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == ")" ? "\<Right>" : ")"
```

The problem occurs in the interaction of these two maps.  That is, say my code is:

```
func(foo)
```

I realize that foo is not a value, but a function, and what I *really* want is to pass the return value from calling `foo()` to func, so I go ahead and move my cursor -- signified by `|` between the `o` and `)`:

```
func(foo|)
```

Now what I *want* to do is simply tap `(` twice, which will trigger my first map and leave me with:

```
func(foo())
```

But in fact, because of my second map, what I get is this:

```
func(foo()
```

How can I create an exception to my 2nd map so that it won't interfere with this specific case?  That is, when the typed `)` is caused by another map rather than by me physically hitting a key, I don't want the 2nd map to be triggered.

Comment: use `inoremap` instead of `imap`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood you, all you need to do is change your first map to:

```
inoremap (( ()<left>
```

This will ignore mappings on the right side and therefore will not trigger your second mapping. I tried it out and is seemed to work for me.